# Angularjs directive for several ng-options inside single controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Angularjs newbie. I have a controller.

```
<div ng-controller='ConfigurableInputController as configurableInput'>
```

and couple of ng-options inside the above controller declarations:

```
<select class="dropdown-1" 
                ng-show="configurableInput.selectedCriteria === 'Channel'" 
                ng-model="configurableInput.selectedChannel1" 
                ng-options="channel for channel in configurableInput.channelList">
            <option value="">--Please select the channel--</option>
        </select>

        <select class="dropdown-2" 
                ng-show="configurableInput.selectedCriteria === 'Channel'" 
                ng-model="configurableInput.selectedChannel2" 
                ng-options="channel for channel in configurableInput.channelList">
            <option value="">--Please select the channel--</option>
        </select>

        <select 
            class="dropdown-1" 
            ng-show="configurableInput.retailArray.length > 0" 
            ng-model="configurableInput.selectedRetailLocation1" 
            ng-options="item1.retailLocation1 as item1.retailLocation1 for item1 in configurableInput.retailLocArray | filter : { retailLocation1 : '!!' }">
            <option value="">--Please select Store Id--</option>
        </select>

        <select 
            class="dropdown-2" 
            ng-show="configurableInput.retailArray.length > 0" 
            ng-model="configurableInput.selectedRetailLocation2" 
            ng-options="item2.retailLocation2 as item2.retailLocation2 for item2 in configurableInput.retailLocArray | filter : { retailLocation2 : '!!' }">
            <option value="">--Please select Store Id--</option>
        </select>
```

How can I have a directive which I can reuse for all the above 4 ng-options?

Comment: I know this probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but using a directive in this instance doesn't really save you anything. It actually introduces additional complexity. What you're wanting to do primarily with a directive is create a reusable chunk of code that'll save you time in the future. When I've used directives, I use them mostly to provide templating for more complex controls (a user drop-down menu, for example).

Comment: Thanks jwilkins88. I now know it isn't only me who was thinking that making directives out of this is going to complicate the matter. I think I will leave these ng-options sitting pretty as they are.